# How are $R$-modules with negativity condition $R_iM_j\subset M_{j-i}$ related to graded $R$-modules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, graded-modules

Let's say we have a graded ring $R=\bigoplus_{i=0}^n R_i$ ($R_m=0$ for $m > n$), in particular we have $R_i R_j \subset R_{i+j}$.

We now have a $R$-module $M$ which is also graded $M=\bigoplus_{i=0}^m M_i$, but instead of the common condition $R_iM_j \subset M_{j+i}$ we have a somehow "inverted" condition $R_iM_j \subset M_{j-i}$ for $i \geq j$ (or for all $i,j$ by setting $M_k=0$ for $k<0$).

I tried to somehow rearrange or invert $R$ to get the original definition, but it didn't work out: We could inverse the grading of $R$ to get $R'=\bigoplus_{i=-n}^0R_{-i}$ which would give a real graded $R'$-module $M$ with $R'_iM_j=R_{-i}M_j\subset M_{j+i}$. However, $R'$ is no more a graded ring because only non-negative indices are allowed for the grading. How can this dilemma be solved?

Is $M$ with this negativity condition still a graded $R$-module? If yes, how can we prove that and if no, are there any counter examples or is there a special name for this type of "modules"? I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Do you really want $M_{i-j}$ and not $M_{j-i}$ (or something else)?  If you take $M_{i-j}$ you run into problems with associativity (consider what degree $R_iR_jM_k$ should be in).

Comment: Oh yeah, you are correct, I mixed up the indices and I meant $M_{j-i}$, I corrected it

Comment: You say in the question "I tried to somehow rearrange ... but it didn't work out". Were you using the wrong indices (that you've now corrected) then? If so, that might have been the only reason it didn't work out ...

Comment: No, I used the corrected indices, it was just a typo in the question. I don't see, how I can get the original condition for graded modules...

Comment: Do you guys have any other suggestion besides the one I've added  - and that sadly didn't work out?